# iftoggle with minipage : error missing number, Illegal unit of measure

Tags: listings, minipage

while combining **iftoggle** with **minipage**, I have got the following error message :

```
Missing number, treated as zero }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) 
Emergency stop
Text dropped after begin of listing
```

`\iftoggle` works fine combined with lstlisting (without minipage). But I would like to get 2 listings side by side, either C and Python or C++ and Python depending on toggletrue...

Thanks for help !

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % classe de document
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % encodage des caractères d'entrée
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % encodage de la police
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}% langue

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{LANGC}
\toggletrue{LANGC}  

\begin{document}

\iftoggle{LANGC}{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption=code C,frame=tlrb]{Name}
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
printf(" %d", i);
i = i + 1;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
print " ", i
i = i + 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
}{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=code C++,frame=tlrb]{Name}
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
cout << i;
i = i + 1;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
print " ", i
i = i + 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
}         <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< error here !
\end{document}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: listings is a verbatim environment and you can not use verbatim constructs in the argument of another command

Comment: But I can use lstlisting inside minipage and lstlisting inside iftoggle...? The problem seems to be minipage inside iftoggle, isnt' it ?

Comment: `\toggle{...}{\begin{lstlisting}....}{...}` might compile, but it does not give the correct result. If you need on off switches with listings, use real `\if...` constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a `lstlisting` environment in the argument to another command. It's easy to have a “free standing” form:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % classe de document
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % encodage des caractères d'entrée
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % encodage de la police
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}% langue

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{LANGC}
\toggletrue{LANGC}

\newcommand{\doiftoggle}[1]{\iftoggle{#1}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\doiftoggle{LANGC}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption=code C,frame=tlrb]{Name}
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
printf(" %d", i);
i = i + 1;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
print " ", i
i = i + 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\else
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=code C++,frame=tlrb]{Name}
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
cout << i;
i = i + 1;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
print " ", i
i = i + 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\fi

\togglefalse{LANGC}

\doiftoggle{LANGC}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption=code C,frame=tlrb]{Name}
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
printf(" %d", i);
i = i + 1;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
print " ", i
i = i + 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\else
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=code C++,frame=tlrb]{Name}
int i = 1;
while (i <= 10) {
cout << i;
i = i + 1;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
print " ", i
i = i + 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fine... ! I have to learn more about Latex ...because i don't understand why \iftoggle works inside your command ? and why is there else and fi without if ? I cannot see braces delimiting code to insert when true or false in the iftoggle...Latex is really for Expert users (thanks to you), I can just copy and paste before spending months and months to learn...

Comment: @PatrickDezecache I just use the standard TeX conditionals; the starting `\if...` is provided by the expansion of `\iftoggle{LANGC}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}`, which is `\iftrue` when the toggle is true and `\iffalse` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments, I will try with **if** structure (SEE BOTTOM...), but for the moment  I changed **lstlisting** to **lstinputlisting**...some more effort to export source files, but a chance to check them more easily

```
        \iftoggle{LANGC}{%
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[language=C,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en C},frame=tlrb]{code000.c}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[language=Python,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en Python},frame=tlrb]{code000.py}
        \end{minipage}
        }{%
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[language=C++,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en C++},frame=tlrb]{code000.c++}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[language=Python,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en Python},frame=tlrb]{code000.py}
        \end{minipage}
        }
```

or even shorter :

```
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \iftoggle{LANGC}{%
        \lstinputlisting[language=C,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en C},frame=tlrb]{code000.c}
        }{%
        \lstinputlisting[language=C++,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en C++},frame=tlrb]{code000.c++}
        }
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \lstinputlisting[language=Python,caption={Compter de 1 à 10 en Python},frame=tlrb]{code000.py}
        \end{minipage}
```

### EDIT 1

**\if**... works fine !

adding :

```
    \newif\iflangageC
    \langageCtrue
```

and **lstlisting** :

```
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \iflangageC
          \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption=code C,frame=tlrb]{Name}
          int i = 1;
          while (i <= 10) {
            printf(" %d", i);
            ++i;
          }
          \end{lstlisting}
        \else
          \begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption=code C++,frame=tlrb]{Name}
          int i = 1;
          while (i <= 10) {
            cout << " " << i;
            ++i;
           }
          \end{lstlisting}
        \fi
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=code Python ,frame=tlrb,firstnumber=1]{Name}
        i = 1
        while (i <= 10):
           print " ", i
           i = i + 1
         }
        \end{lstlisting}
        \end{minipage}
```